# I can't figure out why my program is asking for multiple inputs

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to solve a problem where:

Little girl Tanya is learning how to decrease a number by one, but she does it wrong with a number consisting of two or more digits. Tanya subtracts one from a number by the following algorithm:

if the last digit of the number is non-zero, she decreases the number by one;
if the last digit of the number is zero, she divides the number by 10 (i.e. removes the last digit).
You are given an integer number . Tanya will subtract one from it  times. Your task is to print the result after all  subtractions.

It is guaranteed that the result will be positive integer number.

Input
The first line of the input contains two integer numbers  and  (2≤≤109, 1≤≤50) — the number from which Tanya will subtract and the number of subtractions correspondingly.

Output
Print one integer number — the result of the decreasing  by one  times.

It is guaranteed that the result will be positive integer number.

Examples

inputCopy

```
512 4
```

outputCopy

```
50
```

inputCopy

```
1000000000 9
```

outputCopy

```
1
```

Note
The first example corresponds to the following sequence: 512→511→510→51→50.

(Problem taken from: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/977/A)

My solution:

```
/*
    Wrong subtraction solution
    Alienator5000  
*/  
namespace WrongSubtractionAlienator5000
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Math m = new Math();
            m.doingMath();
            Console.Write(m.forReturning);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }                                                                                                

    class Math
    {
        private string inputValue;
        private int inputValue2;

        public int forReturning;

        public int doingMath()
        {

            inputValue = Console.ReadLine(); //n
            inputValue2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //k

            while (inputValue2 > 0 && inputValue != null)
            {
                string checkValue = inputValue.Remove(0, inputValue.Length - 1);

                if (checkValue != "0")
                {
                    int newInputValue = Convert.ToInt32(inputValue);
                    newInputValue = newInputValue - 1;
                    inputValue2++; //k
                    forReturning = newInputValue;
                }
                else if (checkValue == "0")
                {
                    int newInputValue = Convert.ToInt32(inputValue);
                    newInputValue = newInputValue % 10;
                    inputValue2++; //k
                    forReturning = newInputValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("Incorrect Input");
                }
            }
            return forReturning;
        }
    }
}
```

My debugger isn't working properly so I can't really proceed with my code to see if it's right or not, but I just wanted to know what I can do to make sure there's only 2 input taken and not more. Thank you!

Comment: Why is it important that you need to check if there are more than two values available in the input?

Comment: So you do k/inputValue2  number of Operations. But wich specific operation you do, depend on what the numbers last digit currently is. (divide by 10 if 0, -1 for everything else | You should make both value a integer. You can check for the special case using Modulo. `if(currentValue %10 == 0)` | If you handle string inputs, you just run into issues with placeholder characters like "," or ".", depending on culture.

Comment: _"My debugger isn't working properly"_ -- sounds like your first step is to figure out what's wrong with your debugger. Stack Overflow isn't a "I can't figure out my tools, so I'll let someone else do the work" site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure you only get two inputs, you have to get the first input, then validate it, then if met all requirements, you can get the second one. One way of restricting is using a loop, to keep the user inside this loop until the user entered valid input, then it breaks from the loop to continue executing the reset of the code.

To keep things simple and clear, the `Wrong Subtraction` problem requires two inputs with the following requirements.

- [Input 1] ***n*** should be a valid integer between 2 and 1,000,000,000
- [Input 2] ***k*** should be a valid integer between 1 and 50
- [Result] should be a positive integer.

So, if we take the first input, we can use `while` loop to keep the user inside this loop while validating the input, if we get a valid input, we simply break from this loop, if user entered invalid input, we ask the user to re-enter a valid integer.

Example :

```
int n;

// Get the first input, keep the user in this loop until you get a vaild integer
while (true)
{

    if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n))
    {
        // not a valid integer 
        Console.WriteLine("(n) Incorrect Input, please try again!");
    }
    else if (!(n >= 2 && n <= 1000000000))
    {
        // (n) should be between 2 and 1,000,000,000 
        Console.WriteLine("(n) please choose integer between 2 and 1,000,000,000‬");
    }
    else
    {
        // it's a valid integer and between 2 and 1,000,000,000
        break;
    }
}
```

as you can see in the example, I'm forcing the user over this validations, the user won't be able to continue until both conditions are met.

`int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n)` it'll try to parse the user input, if is it a valid integer, then it'll store it in `n` variable, and it'll return `true`. If is an invalid integer, it'll return `false`, and since it's inside the loop, it'll ask the user to re-enter a valid integer again. We can do the same thing for the `k` input.

here is a full example of the problem solution :

```
class Math
{
    private int n;

    private int k;

    public int DoingMath()
    {


        // Get the first input, keep the user in this loop until you get a vaild integer
        while (true)
        {
            if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n))
            {
                // not a valid integer 
                Console.WriteLine("(n) Incorrect Input, please try again!");
            }
            else if (!(n >= 2 && n <= 1000000000))
            {
                // (n) should be between 2 and 1,000,000,000 
                Console.WriteLine("(n) please choose integer between 2 and 1,000,000,000‬");
            }
            else
            {
                // it's a valid integer and between 2 and 1,000,000,000
                break;
            }


        }

        // Get the second input, keep the user in this loop until you get a vaild integer
        while (true)
        {
            if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out k))
            {
                // not a valid integer 
                Console.WriteLine("(k) Incorrect Input, please try again!");
            }
            else if (!(k >= 1 && k <= 50))
            {
                // (k) should be between 1 and 50           
                Console.WriteLine("(k) please choose integer between 1 and 50.");
            }
            else
            {
                // it's a valid integer and between 1 and 50 
                break;
            }
        }

        // now, do the subtraction logic 
        for (int x = 0; x < k; x++)
        {
            if (n < 10) // if n has one digit, then decrease the number
            {
                n--;
            }
            else // if n has more than one digit 
            {
                var lastDigit = int.Parse(n.ToString().Substring(n.ToString().Length - 1));

                if (lastDigit > 0)
                    n--;
                else
                    n = n / 10;
            }
        }

        return System.Math.Abs(n); // always returns positive number 
    }
}
```

usage :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Math m = new Math();


        // Optional loop, if you want to keep the application running until the user close it.
        while(true)
        {
            var result = m.DoingMath();

            Console.WriteLine(result);

            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue ? [Yes/No]");

            var doContinue = Console.ReadLine();

            if (doContinue.ToLower().Trim().Equals("no"))
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic "ask for input until the user starts making sense" code:

```
int inputValue;
bool repeat = true;

do{
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter first Number");
  string input = Console.ReadLine();

  bool validInput = int.TryParse(input, out inputValue);

  if(validInput)
    repeat = false;
  else
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input. Press any key to try again");
    Console.ReadKey();
}while(repeat);
```

You do that once for each value. After the loop, you know that variables are set to the valid input integer. Additional checks can be added to the while loop (like them needing to be positive numbers).